# Primary Key in SQL - Default value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working from this database, its one of the first I have tried building:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38ef8

When I try to add this line:

```
Insert Into country (name) values ('US');
```

It says Field 'id' doesn't have a default value. Am I doing my primary key correctly? I have seen people using "auto_incrment" on their primary key like this example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c807a/2

Is that what I should be using?

Comment: Yes, either define the id as `AUTO_INCREMENT` or supply the id values during insert: `Insert Into country (id, name) values (1, 'US'), (2, 'FR');`

Comment: "Is that what I should be using?" What you should use depends on your project requirements.

Comment: A primary key is a column or column set that uniquely identifies a row. The concept doesn't imply that the column value must be handled by the database server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you didn't specify `PRIMARY KEY` column as `AUTO_INCREMENT` then you have to give values manually, for example:

```
INSERT INTO Country(id, name) values(1, 'US');
```

It's up to you wheter use `AUTO_INCREMENT` or not. There are many reasons to do it and many not to do it:

- [Pros and Cons of autoincrement keys on "every table"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997358/pros-and-cons-of-autoincrement-keys-on-every-table)
- [Should each and every table have a primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840162/should-each-and-every-table-have-a-primary-key)

Answer (score 3):

there are the properties of PRIMARY key

1. cant be NULL
2. cant be duplicate

now when you select AUTO_INCREMENT  , every time you use the query

```
Insert Into country (name) values ('US');
```

it automatically generates a number incrementing the highest value existing in the table for the primary key column

but when you do not set the primary key as AUTO_INCREMENT ,

```
Insert Into country (name) values ('US');
```

this query will enter NULL values in every column for the row except the given column
in that case your PRIMARY_KEY also gets a null value
which clearly contradicts with the definition of PRIMARY_KEY .
that is why you get the error

I hope the explanation serves

Answer (score 1):

If you have not set your primary key as auto increment, you will have to insert that manually in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

The primary key should be set to AUTO_INCREMENT, if it is not so, you will have to set that manually. 
Although you can still insert with specific values after setting the primary key to AUTO_INCREMENT provided the key is not already existing :D