# Can an attribute be both a pk and fk?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, database-design

I got this picture from another question from stackoverflow itself. but i would liked to know if an attribute can have both a primary key and a foreign key.

So for this table i will have:

```
Person(SIN,Name)
Student(SIN, Name,GPA)
Teacher(SIN,Name,Salary)
```

In the tables Student and Teacher will the `SIN` be both the `PRIMARY KEY AND THE FOREIGN KEY`? Someone please clear this doubt?

[image]

Comment: Yes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636106/can-a-foreign-key-act-as-a-primary-key

Comment: The most common reason for this is super-typing/sub-typing.  Usually there's an exclusive arc.  That is, a PERSON can be a STUDENT or a TEACHER, but not both.  Although that isn't always the case:  sometimes a PERSON can be both a STUDENT *and* a TEACHER, e.g. PhD students who are also teaching assistants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course you can have PK and FK at the same time.

PK & FK at the same time means that you want to index on the primary key, but at the same time you want to restrict the values of the PK based on values that exist in another attribute.