# Can a Field act as both Foreign and Primary Keys in the same table?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working with Flask-SQLAlchemy, but I guess this question cuts across different database implementation platforms.

Suppose I have two table models structured as:

`User` (with fields: `user_id` as PRIMARY KEY, `username`, `email`, `password`) and

`UserDetails` (with fields: `f_name`, `l_name`, `dob`, `gender`, `address`, `contact`, `bio` and `user_id` as FOREIGN KEY).

Would it be okay to have `user_id` from `UserDetails` table serve as PRIMARY KEY just as it is FOREIGN KEY on that same table being the only unique column, without having to create a separate `user_details_id` field for this purpose?

Comment: Foriegn key allows duplicates but primary key doesn't. So i guess, you shouldn't do that. Why are you making different table for this? Why not just combine them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636106/can-a-foreign-key-act-as-a-primary-key

Comment: @Nivedita there are actually several reasons to do something like this - see my answer below for some examples.

Comment: @Nivedita: I am creating a web application in which the users sign-up with details that go into the 'users' table. When a user decides to update his details (which is optional), this new information goes into the 'user_details' table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short - yes. Having the same field as a primary key and a foreign key is used to create a 1:0..1 relationship.

A user may have a single record of details, but cannot have multiple records of details, and you cannot have details for users that do not exist or details not associated with users (i.e., a `null` userId).

This kind of design would make sense if you have many users without details (so it makes sense to separate the details to a different table), or if the details are really heavy and you don't want them bloating the users table's storage, where many fast queries are required.

Comment: @Miureinik: Your answer is spot on! Thanks